# How to match a url path with optional elements using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, url, path, pattern-matching

I'm using custom URL paths which I want to map into an object.

My mapping looks like this:

```
browser://{A}/{B}/{C}/{D}/
```

with `{C}` and `{D}` being optional. So a path might look like this:

```
"browser://call/register/ss/hello"
"browser://call/request/"
```

I would like to have the path available as an object ala

```
 elems = {
   A: call,
   B: register,
   C: ss,
   D: hello
 }
```

But right now I can't even get the regex to work... Here is what I'm trying:

```
 var re = /^browser:\/\/([\w\W]+)[\/+]([\w\W]+)[\/+]([\w\W]*)[\/*]([\w\W]*)[\/*]/;
 console.log(re.exec("browser://call/register/ss/hello"));
```

This only seems to work if I include a full path. But when I leave away `{C}` or `{D}`, my regex fails.

**Question**
How do I make `{C}` and `{D}` optional? Is there an easy way to convert the resulting array into an object?

Thanks for help!

Comment: try `var c = 'A'.charCodeAt(0 ); "browser://call//register/ss/hello".split('/') .filter( String ).splice(1) .reduce( function( a, b ){    a[  String.fromCharCode( c++ ) ] = b;
    return a;
 },{})`

Comment: hm. interesting. Let me try

Comment: Genius! Can you make it an answer, so I can check?

Comment: @frequent if want it in array, `"browser://call//register/ss/hello".match(/[\w\d]+/g).slice(1)` even shoter !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex

```
^(browser:\/)(\/([\w\d]+)){2,4}$
```

Tested on [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/)

In case you allow trailing slash, you can try this

```
^(browser:\/\/)(([\w\d]+)\/){2,4}$
```

Or use a little more complex regex if you need to utilize javascript regex engine to extract matched elements for you

```
^(browser:\/\/)(([\w\d]+)\/)(([\w\d]+)\/)(([\w\d]+)\/)?(([\w\d]+)\/)?$
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wbT46/)

Answer (score 1):

use the following code:

```
function toTokens(str){
  var re = /^browser:\/\/([\w\W]+)[\/+]([\w\W]+)[\/+]/;
  var tmp = re.exec(str);
  var obj = tmp[1].split("/");
  obj.push(tmp[2]);
  return obj;
}
```

Test cases:

```
console.log(toTokens("browser://{A}/{B}/"));
console.log(toTokens("browser://{A}/{B}/{C}/"));
console.log(toTokens("browser://{A}/{B}/{C}/{D}/"));
```